# Help interpreting "Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'"

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, packagekit

I am trying to figure out why an application updated. Apparently it shouldn't update automatically, but did, and this caused problems for me.

When I go into the logs at /var/log/apt I see the record of what happened, but I don't fully understand it

```
Start-Date: 2024-02-26  19:09:09
Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'
Install: #list of stuff that was installed    
Upgrade: # list of stuff that was upgraded
End-Date: 2024-02-26  19:10:07
```

My question is what does "Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'" mean? Naively, this looks like I issued the update command but there is nothing that looks at all relevant in the command history. Is this something I did, or something that happened automatically?

Comment: Packagekit is an interface to package management systems like apt, which is typically used by things like [GNOME Software](https://apps.gnome.org/en-GB/Software/), and other such "app store"-like apps. So I'd think you might have used the GUI for this

Comment: so is it possible that a generic call to sudo apt update would have done this, and if so, how to exclude certain applications from the command?

Comment: @sil no, a call to `apt update` wouldn’t do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line indicates that this was a package upgrade initiated by PackageKit. This could be through a software management UI or possibly automatic upgrades.

If you want to keep a specific package from being upgraded, you should hold it:

```
sudo apt-mark hold mypackage
```

This will prevent status changes to the package through APT or any of its frontends, including PackageKit.